# Subscript out of Bound error when running predict function in R

Tags: r, statistics, text-mining

I am working on a text mining project using to classify test using Naive Bayes.

When I build a Naive Bayes classifier using

```
classifier<-naiveBayes(training, type)
```

then run the predict function on test data:

```
pred <- predict(classifier, test)
```

I get:

```
Error in object$tables[[v]][, nd] : subscript out of bounds
```

What would be the cause of this error?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The training and testing data was a Matrix of Characters. When I converted into Numeric, I never faced this problem again.